The axis object cannot be used after being put into an array?
Codesys v3.5 sp20+(32bit)
I hope to power up the specified axis through the following code,It worked.
The following code is called cyclically,It's called by a task every 4 milliseconds.
PROGRAM PowerupTest
VAR
    MC_Power_0: MC_Power;
    Axises:ARRAY[0..5] OF SM3_Drive_ETC_DS402_CyclicSync.AXIS_REF_ETC_DS402_CS;
END_VAR

MC_Power_0(
    Axis:=Axis0, 
    Enable:=1 , 
    bRegulatorOn:=1 , 
    bDriveStart:=1 , 
    Status=> ,
    bRegulatorRealState=> , 
    bDriveStartRealState=> , 
    Busy=> , 
    Error=> , 
    ErrorID=> 
);

Now, to change it a little bit, I save Axis0 into an array first, and then pass the elements of the array into the MC_Power function block.
It doesn't work properly anymore.
Axises[0]:=Axis0;

MC_Power_0(
    Axis:=Axises[0],   //Changed here
    Enable:=1 , 
    bRegulatorOn:=1 , 
    bDriveStart:=1 , 
    Status=> ,
    bRegulatorRealState=> , 
    bDriveStartRealState=> , 
    Busy=> , 
    Error=> , 
    ErrorID=> 
);

Could you tell me the possible reason?
I hope I can access all axes as an array.
Thank you.
=========================
I made the following changes, but it still doesn't work.
PROGRAM PowerupTest
VAR
    MC_Power_0: MC_Power;
    Axises:ARRAY[0..5] OF SM3_Drive_ETC_DS402_CyclicSync.AXIS_REF_ETC_DS402_CS;
    IsInitialized:BOOL:=false;
END_VAR

IF NOT IsInitialized THEN
    Axises[0]:=Axis0;
    IsInitialized:=TRUE;
    RETURN;
END_IF



MC_Power_0(
    Axis:=Axises[0], 
    Enable:=1 , 
    bRegulatorOn:=1 , 
    bDriveStart:=1 , 
    Status=> ,
    bRegulatorRealState=> , 
    bDriveStartRealState=> , 
    Busy=> , 
    Error=> GVL.LastError, 
    ErrorID=> GVL.LastErrorId
);


I haven't used AXIS_REF_ETC_DS402_CS, but I assume there are some variables that are linked to hardware I/O? When you assign Axises[0]:=Axis0 what happens is that the block is copied and then Axis0 does not change anymore.  So when a value in Axises[0] changes, Axis0 does not change. I think you should get rid of Axis0 and use the array item directly.

Problem solved, I should use a pointer to save the reference to the axis object
PROGRAM PowerupTest
VAR
    MC_Power_0: MC_Power;
    Axises:ARRAY[0..5] OF POINTER TO SM3_Drive_ETC_DS402_CyclicSync.AXIS_REF_ETC_DS402_CS;
    IsInitialized:BOOL:=false;
END_VAR


Axises[0]:=ADR(Axis0);

MC_Power_0(
    Axis:=Axises[0]^, 
    Enable:=1 , 
    bRegulatorOn:=1 , 
    bDriveStart:=1 , 
    Status=> ,
    bRegulatorRealState=> , 
    bDriveStartRealState=> , 
    Busy=> , 
    Error=> , 
    ErrorID=> 
);


I assume the code shown is called cyclically.
Then, it seems likely to me that the problem is that you overwrite Axis[0] with the content of Axis0 every cycle. Since Axis0 is not used, its internal state never changes, so anything that was done to Axis[0] as part of the call to MC_Power_0 is wiped out.
Why to you have Axises[0]:=Axis0;? If there is some initialization done to Axis0 that you want to transfer to Axis[0], you can do the same directly with Axis[0] instead. If you really want to keep this line, make sure it is called only once at the beginning of your program rather than at every cycle.

Thanks.
Yes,code is called cyclically,It's called by the "EtherCAT_Task" every 4 milliseconds.
I put axis0 into an array because I wish I could access all 6 Axises as an array.
I tried some things but still failed. The new code has been updated above.

I do not understand why you include Axises[0]:=ADR(Axis0), and I suspect your problem may be come from something we cannot see. Get rid of Axis0 altogether, delete its definition. The array contains valid instances. Just use Axis[0] everywhere.
